# Enter a MAC address in the right format on Android

Tags: android, regex, validation

I have an EditText and I want the user to be able to enter a MAC address.

How can I limit the user to only enter A, B, C..F and numbers and write them in the correct format (00:11:22:33:44:55)?

How do I validate?

EDIT: I found this code that does what I need but with an IP address. I tried to use the regex you suggested, but they don't work.

```
    public void showIP(){
    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    input.setSingleLine();
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    //filter used to allow only IPv4 style address
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                if (!resultingTxt.matches("^[\\dA-F]{2}(?::[\\dA-F]{2}){5}$")) { 
                    return "";
                } /*else {
                    String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\:");
                    for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                        if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > ) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }*/
            }
        return null;
        }
    };
    input.setFilters(filters);

    input.setText(serverIP);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.ServerIP)
        .setMessage("Change SERVER IP")
        .setView(input)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                serverIP=input.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("IP", input.getText().toString());
                // Commit the edits!
                editor.commit();
                view.updateServerIP();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }).show();
}
```

Comment: Just have 4 fields or make a single one works dinamycally (ads the ':' etc).

Comment: I make a single one works dinamically

Comment: separators can be hyphens `-` or colons `:`

Answer (score 6):

In this code MAC Address Field will auto generate ':' . You can remove that condition too.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(context);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
        input.setSingleLine();
        InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];

        filters[0] = new InputFilter() {


            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (end > start) {
                    String destTxt = dest.toString();
                    String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                    if (resultingTxt.matches("([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){0,5}[0-9a-fA-F]"))
                    {

                    }
                    else if(resultingTxt.matches("([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){0,4}[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]")){
                        return source.subSequence(start, end)+":" ;
                    }
                    else if(resultingTxt.matches("([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){0,5}[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]")){

                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        return "";
                    } 
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        input.setFilters(filters);
```

Comment: pressing delete on a colon breaks this

Answer (score 0):

The general regex to match a char from 0-F would be `[\dA-F]`

So having that in mind, you could do: `^[\dA-F]{2}(?:[\-][\dA-F]{2}){5}$`

Nothe: The  `(?:` Is for a non capturing group.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sH1qR7)

Comment: What edit, you just posted a bunch of code, I gave you the regular expression I'm not gonna compile it for you. Btw I added hyphens as separator too and gave you a demo.

Comment: I did't want you to compile my code -.- I just wanted to know if the functions I used are correct...because I think you're more experienced than me

Answer (score 0):

`([\da-fA-F]{2}(?:\:|$)){6}`

This works well, as you can see here:

http://regexr.com?32ugi

If you wish to have "-" also included as a separator (which is valid as per the standard) you can use this:

`([\da-fA-F]{2}(?:\:|-|$)){6}`

http://regexr.com?32ugl